# Allow / in django url

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I want to make a wiki, and i must assign for each url a view. Each url can contain letters (`A-Z, a-z`), digits and punctuation (`'.', ',', '/', '-', '_'`). How can I make the expression ?

I want something like this :

```
(r'^(?P<wiki_page>\w+)/$', 'www.wiki.views.page')
```

but this works only for letters, digits and '_'.

Answer (score 5):

Try this regexp:

```
r'^(?P<wiki_page>[\w.,/_\-]+)/$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace \w in the regex with a regex to match what you're looking for.  Perhaps

```
(r'^(?P<wiki_page>[A-Za-z_/,\.-]+)$, 'www.wiki.views.page')
```

or similar.

Comment: You forgot to include digits (`0-9`)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a regex question

```
r'^(?P<wiki_page>[\w\.,_/\-]+)/$'
```

you can build character classes on top of existing ones

I think you have to escape the dash, or put it last, because dash defines range of characters and you may get a very unexpected side-effect of dash.